# What is the most efficient way to load data into Tensorflow for real time inference?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

When setting up a data input pipeline to Tensorflow (web cam images), a large amount of time is spent loading the data from the system RAM to the GPU memory.

I am trying to feed a constant stream of images (1024x1024) through my object detection network. I'm currently using a V100 on AWS to perform inference.

The first attempt was with a simple feed dict operation.

```
# Get layers
img_input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/input_image:0')
img_anchors_input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/input_anchors:0')
img_meta_input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/input_image_meta:0')
detections_input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/output_detections:0')

detections = sess.run(detections_input_tensor,
                 feed_dict={img_input_tensor: molded_image, img_meta_input_tensor: image_meta, img_anchors_input_tensor: image_anchor})
```

This produced inference times around 0.06 ms per image.

However, after reading the Tensorflow manual I noticed that the `tf.data` API was recommended for loading data for inference.

```
# setup data input
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((img_input_tensor, img_meta_input_tensor, img_anchors_input_tensor, detections_input_tensor))
iterator = data.make_initializable_iterator()  # create the iterator
next_batch = iterator.get_next()

# load data
sess.run(iterator.initializer,
                 feed_dict={img_input_tensor: molded_image, img_meta_input_tensor: image_meta, img_anchors_input_tensor: image_anchor})

# inference
detections = sess.run([next_batch])[0][3]
```

This sped up inference time to 0.01ms, put the time taken to load the data took 0.1 ms. This `Iterator` methods is much longer than the 'slower' `feed_dict` method significantly. Is there something I can do to speed up the loading process?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) is a great guide on data pipeline optimization. I personally find the `.prefetch` method the easiest way to boost your input pipeline. However, the article provides much more advanced techniques.

However, if your input data is not in tfrecords, but you feed it by yourself, you have to implement the described techniques (buffering, interleaved operations) somehow by yourself.